# Unable to use bot from Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a bot that works well from the emulator or through the web channel.
However, I can't manage to use it from Teams.
I got an error saying this channel is not enabled. But it is, so I guess I'm missing something.

[image]

Comment: What's the name of your bot?  I can look it up and try to see what's going on.   (On BF team at MS)

Comment: I'll send you an email :)

Comment: Having the same issue on my end.  Everything was working fine until this morning, suddenly the above indicated error is being thrown constantly.  Web Chat channel working just fine still..

Comment: see accepted answer from @Lars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed that there is a bug.  If you disable the Skype channel, Teams is also disabled.   Work around for the moment is to re-add the Skype channel.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this toggle turned on inside the Microsoft Teams channel on Bot Framework?

[image: Enable the channel]

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. I even tried to turn it off and on again to be sure.