# Microsoft Bot Framework bot not working in Microsoft Teams when using ngrok

Tags: botframework, botconnector, microsoft-teams

My Bot is working in the Emulator and through other channels but it's not working on Microsoft Teams.

I able to see other channels requests and responses statuss in ngrok. But when using Microsoft Teams, request are not even hitting my server URL (ngrok).

[image: Microsoft Team Enabled and Webchat getting response]

App ID :**dfc6ac0d-e805-4a40-9fd3-7c4678b7ae88**

(It's not duplicate of [Unable to use bot from Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564257/unable-to-use-bot-from-teams))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello:  I was able to access the Bot and get a response (character count of my message.)  Perhaps you didn't enable sideloading of bots in the Office Admin Portal?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/setup