# Microsoft Teams Bot not sending requests to bot messaging endpoint

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Web chat works fine (posts to my endpoint), but when sending either a direct message or tagging the bot in a message in a public channel, the endpoint I registered for the bot doesn't receive a request.

**NOTE: It worked for a brief period yesterday, but not since. I've deleted the app and bot and repeated the below steps multiple times with no success.**

Here are the steps I walked through to create the app and bot user and install the app to Microsoft teams:

1. Created a new bot here - https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new and set the messaging endpoint to my desired endpoint (a live endpoint that currently just logs the request). *EDIT: Yes I activated the Microsoft Teams Channel for the bot as well*
2. Used the App Studio teams app to generate a valid manifest file and used the id of the bot created earlier as the bot user id for the app.
3. Uploaded the app manifest as a custom app in teams and installed it to my team.

The bot installs properly and shows up in my team, but no requests are sent to my endpoint when messaging it.

This is possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500719/microsoft-bot-framework-bot-not-working-in-microsoft-teams-when-using-ngrok) but that answer appears to be either outdated or simply not applicable in my case.

Comment: Could you please share your bot id? Are you running your code [locally using ngrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#tunnel-using-ngrok)?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT bot id is: 9569ec69-c6ff-405d-89f1-7eaf11b63595. I'm using serveo because it allows me to keep a specific subdomain for free, but yeah other than that it does the same thing. And I've confirmed that the endpoint is available publicly and that my server logs all incoming requests.

Comment: Tried it for the first time today and now requests are in fact being sent. Nothing changed, but now it works. That worries me about Microsoft Teams.

Comment: This is happening to me as well. If I create a bot from Azure Bot Framework portal, it works intermittently with Teams and ngrok. If I create a bot from Teams App Studio, it works perfectly. Not sure if there is supposed to be a difference between the two?